# nbeats model logging in mlflow not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, mlflow

I am trying to log nbeats model developed using darts library into mlflow ui, but I am not able to do that. I am getting the following error.

PS this model is developed using Darts library. If anyone knows who had developed nbetas and logged in mlflow. Kindly mention the source for my reference.

*RuntimeError: [enforce fail at C:\cb\pytorch_1000000000000\work\c10\core\impl\alloc_cpu.cpp:81] data. DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 16515072 bytes.*

My code is as folows:

```
from darts.models import LightGBMModel, RandomForest, NaiveMean, NBEATSModel
from data_preparation import darts_x_train, darts_y_train, darts_y_val, df_x

import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import mlflow
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import torch

print(torch.__version__)

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARN)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
lags = [-4, -24 * 4, -12 * 4, -8 * 4 * 24, -7 * 24 * 4, -10 * 4 * 24, -11 * 4 * 24, -12 * 4 * 24]
lags_future = [0, 4, 8, 12 * 4, 24 * 4, 48 * 4]
output_chunk_length = 4  # int(pd.Timedelta('2w') / (darts_x_train.time_index[1] - 
darts_x_train.time_index[0]))
print(output_chunk_length, "output_chunk_length timesteps")
last_two_weeks = darts_y_val.time_index[-1] - pd.Timedelta(days=16)
test_series = darts_y_val.drop_after(last_two_weeks)

def baseline_model():
    nbeats_model = NBEATSModel(input_chunk_length=672, output_chunk_length=output_chunk_length, n_epochs=1,
                           random_state=42,
                           pl_trainer_kwargs={
                               "accelerator": "gpu",
                               "devices": [0]
                           }, )

return nbeats_model

def mlflow_run(run_name="nbeats_model_run"):

    model_uri = mlflow.get_artifact_uri("model")
    # Start MLflow run and log everyting...
    with mlflow.start_run(run_name=run_name, nested=True) as run:
    model = baseline_model()
    mlflow.keras.log_model(keras_model=model, keras_module= tf.keras, artifact_path='artifacts')
    model.fit(darts_y_train, past_covariates=darts_x_train, epochs=1)
    model.predict(n=1344, series=test_series, past_covariates=df_x)
    run_id = run.info.run_uuid
    exp_id = run.info.experiment_id

    return exp_id, run_id


 if __name__ == '__main__':
# suppress any deprecated warnings
 warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

 (exp_id, run_id) = mlflow_run()
 print(f"Finished Experiment id={exp_id} and run id = {run_id}")
```

> C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\python.exe "C:/Users/R953682/Local_Energy _Consumption/MLW/run_file.py"
> 34397 34397
> 11467 11467
> 1.12.1
> 4 output_chunk_length timesteps
> 2022/09/22 17:31:09 WARNING mlflow.utils.environment: Encountered an unexpected error while inferring pip requirements (model URI: C:\Users\R953682\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnefahsun\model, flavor: keras), fall back to return ['tensorflow==2.9.1', 'keras==2.9.0']. Set logging level to DEBUG to see the full traceback.
> 2022-09-22 17:31:10 pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero INFO: GPU available: True (cuda), used: True
> 2022-09-22 17:31:10 pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero INFO: TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
> 2022-09-22 17:31:10 pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero INFO: IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
> 2022-09-22 17:31:10 pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero INFO: HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
> 2022-09-22 17:31:10 pytorch_lightning.accelerators.cuda INFO: LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]
> 2022-09-22 17:31:11 pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_summary INFO:
> | Name          | Type             | Params

---

### 0 | criterion     | MSELoss          | 0
1 | train_metrics | MetricCollection | 0
2 | val_metrics   | MetricCollection | 0
3 | stacks        | ModuleList       | 69.4 M

69.3 M    Trainable params
49.7 K    Non-trainable params
69.4 M    Total params
555.182   Total estimated model params size (MB)
Epoch 0: 100%|██████████| 1054/1054 [02:46<00:00,  6.33it/s, loss=0.0392, train_loss=0.0496]
2022-09-22 17:33:57 pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero INFO: `Trainer.fit` stopped: `max_epochs=1` reached.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 650, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 735, in _fit_impl
results = self._run(model, ckpt_path=self.ckpt_path)
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1169, in _run
self._teardown()
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1229, in _teardown
self.strategy.teardown()
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\strategies\strategy.py", line 476, in teardown
self.lightning_module.cpu()
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\core\mixins\device_dtype_mixin.py", line 141, in cpu
return super().cpu()
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 738, in cpu
return self._apply(lambda t: t.cpu())
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 579, in _apply
module._apply(fn)
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 579, in _apply
module._apply(fn)
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 579, in _apply
module._apply(fn)
[Previous line repeated 3 more times]
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 615, in _apply
grad_applied = fn(param.grad)
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 738, in 
return self._apply(lambda t: t.cpu())
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at C:\cb\pytorch_1000000000000\work\c10\core\impl\alloc_cpu.cpp:81] data. DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 16515072 bytes.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\R953682\Local_Energy _Consumption\MLW\run_file.py", line 60, in 
(exp_id, run_id) = mlflow_run()
File "C:\Users\R953682\Local_Energy _Consumption\MLW\run_file.py", line 48, in mlflow_run
model.fit(darts_y_train, past_covariates=darts_x_train, epochs=1)
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\darts\utils\torch.py", line 112, in decorator
return decorated(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\darts\models\forecasting\torch_forecasting_model.py", line 806, in fit
return self.fit_from_dataset(
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\darts\utils\torch.py", line 112, in decorator
return decorated(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\darts\models\forecasting\torch_forecasting_model.py", line 961, in fit_from_dataset
self._train(train_loader, val_loader)
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\darts\models\forecasting\torch_forecasting_model.py", line 983, in _train
self.trainer.fit(
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 696, in fit
self._call_and_handle_interrupt(
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 664, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
self._teardown()
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1229, in _teardown
self.strategy.teardown()
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\strategies\strategy.py", line 476, in teardown
self.lightning_module.cpu()
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\core\mixins\device_dtype_mixin.py", line 141, in cpu
return super().cpu()
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 738, in cpu
return self._apply(lambda t: t.cpu())
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 579, in _apply
module._apply(fn)
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 579, in _apply
module._apply(fn)
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 579, in _apply
module._apply(fn)
[Previous line repeated 3 more times]
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 615, in _apply
grad_applied = fn(param.grad)
File "C:\Users\R953682\Anaconda3\envs\MLflow_tutorial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 738, in 
return self._apply(lambda t: t.cpu())
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at C:\cb\pytorch_1000000000000\work\c10\core\impl\alloc_cpu.cpp:81] data. DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 16515072 bytes.